# Error trying to publish my web app from VS Community 2015 to Azure. Error: Can't find existing loaded project:http://localhost:55809

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015

This was working fine yesterday.
I made several changes to my system (updates from VS Community 15) and the Azure SDK updates, etc., - as was recommended by the software.

Today, when I right click on the web app and select Publish (using the same or manually entered public information) I see the following error on my Azure App Service Activity tab:

`Can't find existing loaded project:http://localhost:55809`

I have since tried other publish profiles, none seem to work.
I can successfully build and run the web app on localhost.

Comment: I would recommend pulling another publish profile from Azure and attempt to publish with the new profile. It may be that some setting on the Azure instance is different and needs to be reflected in the publish profile. You can refresh the publish profile to get a new one on the Azure web application.

Comment: Thank you.  I downloaded a new profile and attempted to publish.  Same result.  I tried (earlier) to move the workspace and re-download from source control and publish and it still failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Publishing via **FTP** to azure instead of WebDeploy worked for me.

Comment: Works for me as well but now I just use an FTP client to push changed files.  Still can't publish correctly but I no longer care because this way is faster anyway.

Comment: Publishing via FTP will take long time. Better to go with Publish..

`Go to View -> Other Windows -> Web Publish Activity -> Click on the Publish web icon` that will work

Comment: Till test environment it is good but for production servers where DevOps team is deploying FTP option is better for them.

Comment: @Nisar this should be the accepted answer, it has been 2 days i am trying to fix this issue,thank you :)

Answer (score 60):

In Visual Studio, go to View -> Other Windows -> Web Publish Activity and you will see the Azure App Service Activity window.

Click on the Publish web icon that you will find there. It should work.

Comment: I don't know why, but it works! It seems that they've introduced a bug on the publish procedure in RC1, but this workarround has saved my day. Thanks

Comment: I had tried this without success.  I believe it was a version/update that finally fixed it.  Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: For me this was an issue of not being signed in the correct MS Account associated with my azure subscription.

Comment: It worked for me. The only possibility I can think of for why it did not work otherwise is that I had previously tried to deploy to a GoDaddy hosted site and that did not work. So then I created an Azure site and used Web Deploy extremely easily except for just this one extra step. My GoDaddy attempts might have done something that required fixing and if so then this fixed it.

Comment: not working for some web project which does not have project file, not sure VS 2015 not creating a project file for my static website. However, the ftp deployment is working fine.

Comment: What the hell...?  First off, thank you... this fixed my Publish to Azure problem perfectly... but what the heck has Microsoft broken ?  Previously, just right-clicking on the project, and doing "Publish Web App" (with the Azure Publishing Profile) worked fine... Now, it doesn't, and I have to go via this hidden-away "Web Publish Activity" Publish button.  Aaaagghh!!!

Answer (score 5):

Change the deploy method to Ftp then change it right back to "Web Deploy".  This keeps working for me

Answer (score 2):

In the project folder in the **website.publishproj** file change the **SourceWebProject** tag to contain your client name instead of the localhost.

At least this worked for me :)

**Update 13 Dec 2015:**

Having the same problem again. The previously mentioned fix does not work. However publishing via FTP to azure works. 
When you get the azure publish profile you get both Web Deploy and FTP. Try using FTP.

Comment: grr, nope.  What is strange is it doesn't matter what I put in there for SourceWebProject, the error remains the same.  I even put in a completely invalid string and the error message remains.

Comment: That's strange.  My publish to FTP didn't work but today.. because I had a minute to try it, I published to a testing deployment slot I hadn't used in a couple weeks and it worked.  
I suspect it has something to do with the recent VS Community update I installed a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

An update of Visual Studio Community 2015 to version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1 seems to have corrected the problem.

Update or install from here.  [Visual Studio Community Download from Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)